# Настройка дебага в vscode windows 10

Tags: json, visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-code

Пишу весь код в вскоде и компилирую в gcc, установлен весь basic пак. Очень хотелось бы настроить дебаг нормально тк без него тяжело писать большие по объему программы[image: Вот что выходит при попытке запустить дебаг]

А вот и launch.json
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Кажется достаточно указать путь в`launch.json` чтоб все заработало:

`"miDebuggerPath": "c:\\mingw\\bin\\gdb.exe"`
и
`"coreDumpPath": "c:\\..\\temp-dir"`

Вообще то эти сокральные знания изложены в Хелпе к [продукту](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_debugging)

Ну и расказ в [картинках](https://habr.com/company/microsoft/blog/333680/)

Comment: Попробовал добавить midebug... и coredump..., пишет, что не находит a.exe, когда в рабочей папке именно такая скомпилированная программа есть

Comment: А на статье с хабра под линукс написано :c

Comment: Пути поправьте, настройки не должны зависеть от ос, они одинаковые, а `а.ехе` надо поменять на имя исполняемого файла собираемого вами приложения :)